# erlang socket (using ranch) close in a short time?

Tags: sockets, erlang, ranch

i use ranch to listen socket, but in a short time about five seconds, ranch closed the socket, and my setting of socket is above, so what' wrong?

```
    {ok, _} = ranch:start_listener(server,200, ranch_tcp, [{port, 5555},{active, once},    {max_connections, 1024}], server_protocol, []), %% start the listener
```

the protocol file is below, the ranch listen to accept a socket, and the reverse the receive data, but what's wrong is that, when send data back to the client, after about five seconds, the client receive the message says that the socket is closed by server, i don't know if is ranch's default settings cause this?

```
-module(reverse_protocol).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-behaviour(ranch_protocol).
%% API.
-export([start_link/4]).
%% gen_server.
-export([init/1]).
-export([init/4]).
-export([handle_call/3]).
-export([handle_cast/2]).
-export([handle_info/2]).
-export([terminate/2]).
-export([code_change/3]).
-define(TIMEOUT, 5000).
-record(state, {socket, transport}).

%% API.
start_link(Ref, Socket, Transport, Opts) ->
proc_lib:start_link(?MODULE, init, [Ref, Socket, Transport, Opts]).
%% gen_server.
%% This function is never called. We only define it so that
%% we can use the -behaviour(gen_server) attribute.

init([]) -> {ok, undefined}.

init(Ref, Socket, Transport, _Opts = []) ->
ok = proc_lib:init_ack({ok, self()}),
ok = ranch:accept_ack(Ref),
ok = Transport:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
gen_server:enter_loop(?MODULE, [],
    #state{socket=Socket, transport=Transport},
    ?TIMEOUT).

handle_info({tcp, Socket, Data}, State=#state{
    socket=Socket, transport=Transport}) ->
Transport:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
Transport:send(Socket, reverse_binary(Data)),
{noreply, State, ?TIMEOUT};

handle_info({tcp_closed, _Socket}, State) ->
{stop, normal, State};

handle_info({tcp_error, _, Reason}, State) ->
{stop, Reason, State};

handle_info(timeout, State) ->
{stop, normal, State};

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
{stop, normal, State}.

handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
{reply, ok, State}.

handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
{noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
{ok, State}.

%% Internal.
reverse_binary(B) when is_binary(B) ->
[list_to_binary(lists:reverse(binary_to_list(
    binary:part(B, {0, byte_size(B)-2})
))), "\r\n"].
```

Comment: How did you determine that ranch closed the listening socket?

Comment: the client print out the reason, and i also try to connect to a python socket server, it works ok! @evnu

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example exhibiting the problem?

Comment: ok, i add this to question description at once.@evnu

Comment: i add more detail to this question, and thanks to give me an advice.@evnu

Answer (score 2):

So your problem is because your gen_server process is timing out and shutting down. The socket being closed is a side effect of this because ranch links the Socket to the spawned handler process.

Once the new process enters the gen_server loop with the call to `gen_server:enter_loop`, it has `?TIMEOUT` milliseconds to receive a message before it is sent a `timeout` message.

```
-define(TIMEOUT, 5000).

init(Ref, Socket, Transport, _Opts = []) ->
  ok = proc_lib:init_ack({ok, self()}),
  ok = ranch:accept_ack(Ref),
  ok = Transport:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
  gen_server:enter_loop(?MODULE, [],
    #state{socket=Socket, transport=Transport},
    ?TIMEOUT). %% timeout because of this!

handle_info({tcp, Socket, Data}, State=#state{
  socket=Socket, transport=Transport}) ->
  Transport:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
  Transport:send(Socket, reverse_binary(Data)),
  {noreply, State, ?TIMEOUT}; %% timeout because of this!
```

So when those five second pass and the gen_server hasn't received any messages in that time it sends itself a `timeout` message, which is then handled by `handle_info`

```
handle_info(timeout, State) ->
  {stop, normal, State};
```

Your `handle_info` tells the gen_server to stop, which causes the Socket to close because the two are linked together.

You can either remove the timeouts completely, or just stop the timeout from causing the process to close.

Here is how I would change the `handle_info` timeout code:

```
handle_info(timeout, State) ->
  io:format("the socket is idle~n"),
  {noreply,State};
```